# python python3 pip3... How to clear the mess?

Tags: python

Basic information:

```
kali@kali:~$ uname -a
Linux kali 5.9.0-kali5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.9.15-1kali1 (2020-12-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Python:

```
kali@kali:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
kali@kali:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.18
```

Python3:

```
kali@kali:~$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
kali@kali:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.0
```

Pip:

```
kali@kali:~$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
kali@kali:~$ pip3 --version
pip 20.3.3 from /home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

PATH:

```
kali@kali:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

### Questions:

1. Why pip3 was located at `/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip`?
2. How this did not work:

```
kali@kali:~/Downloads/sparrow-wifi$ python3 sparrow-wifi.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Downloads/sparrow-wifi/sparrow-wifi.py", line 33, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow,  QDesktopWidget, QGraphicsSimpleTextItem, QFrame, QGraphicsView
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'
```

Try again:

```
kali@kali:~/Downloads/sparrow-wifi$ ./sparrow-wifi.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Downloads/sparrow-wifi/./sparrow-wifi.py", line 28, in <module>
    from dateutil import parser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateutil'
```

Try the 3rd time:

```
kali@kali:~/Downloads/sparrow-wifi$ python sparrow-wifi.py 
  File "sparrow-wifi.py", line 3369
    filesWin.exec()
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Try to install PyQt5 by `pip3`:

```
kali@kali:~/Downloads/sparrow-wifi$ pip3 install PyQt5
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting PyQt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.2-5.15.2-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38.cp39-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (68.3 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5_sip-12.8.1-py3.9-linux-x86_64.egg (from PyQt5) (12.8.1)
Installing collected packages: PyQt5
  WARNING: The scripts pylupdate5, pyrcc5 and pyuic5 are installed in '/home/kali/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.                                                       
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.                                                       
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.                                                                                 
wifipumpkin3 1.0.8 requires dhcplib==0.1.1, which is not installed.                  
wifipumpkin3 1.0.8 requires netaddr>=0.7.19, which is not installed.                 
wifipumpkin3 1.0.8 requires netifaces>=0.10.9, which is not installed.               
wifipumpkin3 1.0.8 requires tabulate>=0.8.5, which is not installed.                 
wifipumpkin3 1.0.8 requires termcolor>=1.1.0, which is not installed.                
wifipumpkin3 1.0.8 requires urwid==2.1.1, which is not installed.                    
wifipumpkin3 1.0.8 requires twisted==19.7.0, but you have twisted 20.3.0 which is incompatible.                                                                           
Successfully installed PyQt5-5.15.2
```

Try to install PyQt5 by `pip`:

```
kali@kali:~/Downloads/sparrow-wifi$ pip install PyQt5
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5 in /home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (5.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5_sip-12.8.1-py3.9-linux-x86_64.egg (from PyQt5) (12.8.1)
```

Try to install dateutil by `pip`:

```
kali@kali:~/Downloads/sparrow-wifi$ pip install python-dateutil
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from python-dateutil) (1.15.0)
```

Try to install dateutil by `pip3`:

```
kali@kali:~/Downloads/sparrow-wifi$ pip3 install python-dateutil
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from python-dateutil) (1.15.0)
```

Tried to run `python3 sparrow-wifi.py`, `python sparrow-wifi.py`, and `./sparrow-wifi.py` after install `dateutil` and `PyQt5`, got the same erroe message.

Comment: maybe the environment you are running is 2.7 and the library is installed in python3. in Linux, python2.7 is pre-installed, so python or pip is == python2.7. if you are using python3.x that would be python3 or pip3 == python3.x.

Comment: hey, so the different python files you showed are different python versions, and kali has them pre-installed. For example in python 2 the syntax for input is just raw_input() whereas in python3 it is input().

Comment: Please mention in the question the command and code you're trying to run as python3 that would make it easy to resolve for everyone.

Comment: Have you tried running `pip3` without `sudo`? The pip3 you’ve shown is located in `~/.local`, and that surely won’t be executed by the root user when running via `sudo`. You can verify this by running `sudo which pip3`, which presumably points to a different binary.

Comment: @KonradRudolph `kali@kali:~/Downloads/sparrow-wifi$ sudo which pip3
[sudo] password for kali: 
/usr/local/bin/pip3`